# jQuery error when using $window.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have the following code that works inside a document ready event:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('tr[data-name="background_colour"] input.wp-color-picker').each(function() {

        //this works
        $(this).closest('tr').siblings('tr[data-type="wysiwyg"]').css('background-color', this.value);

        //this doesn't because frames are not loaded
        $(this).closest('tr').siblings('tr[data-type="wysiwyg"]').find('iframe').contents().find('body').css('background-color', this.value);
    });
});
```

The background color of the `tr` is changed successfully but not the `body` of the `iframe` because all iframes are dynamically created and they are not fully loaded yet when document is ready.

So I tried using window.load instead as follows:

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {

    $('tr[data-name="background_colour"] input.wp-color-picker').each(function() {

        //this works
        $(this).closest('tr').siblings('tr[data-type="wysiwyg"]').css('background-color', this.value);

        //this doesn't because frames are not loaded
        $(this).closest('tr').siblings('tr[data-type="wysiwyg"]').find('iframe').contents().find('body').css('background-color', this.value);
    });
});
```

But I got `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` on the line below when I did that:

`$('tr[data-name="background_colour"] input.wp-color-picker').each(function() {`

Got this to work thanks to Guffa's answer. Here is the correct code which might be helpful for other people:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {

    jQuery(function($){

        $('tr[data-name="background_colour"] input.wp-color-picker').each(function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').siblings('tr[data-type="wysiwyg"]').css('background-color', this.value);

            $(this).closest('tr').siblings('tr[data-type="wysiwyg"]').find('iframe').contents().find('body').css('background-color', this.value);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: can you show us your html code or the parent table of the attribute that you are using

Comment: What code is generating the iframes? I suggest moving this code to that location.

Comment: code is generated from a wordpress plugin. html code in a very simplified version is something like https://jsfiddle.net/LcssrmL8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ready` event handler is called with the jQuery object as parameter, but the `load` event handler isn't.

As you have `$` as parameter for the `load` event handler, it will contain the event object, not the jQuery object. When you try to use the event object as if it is the jQuery object, you will get an error.

Remove the parameter from the `load` event handler, so that you can access the `$` variable from the global scope:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
```